# How many arithmetic operations should it take to calculate trig functions?

Tags: math, floating-point, precision, trigonometry, floating-accuracy

I'm trying to assess the expected performance of calculating trigonometry functions as a function of the required precision. Obviously the wall clock time depends on the speed of the underlying arithmetic, so factoring that out by just counting number of operations:

Using state-of-the-art algorithms, how many arithmetic operations (add, subtract, multiply, divide) should it take to calculate `sin(x)`, as a function of the number of bits (or decimal digits) of precision required in the output?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Right, I'm asking for the case of multi-precision calculations.

Comment: For multi-precision arithmetic, I recommend having a look at the MPFR algorithms: https://www.mpfr.org/algorithms.pdf

Comment: @rwallace: Fredrik Johansson, "Efficient implementation of elementary functions in the medium-precision range", In *22nd IEEE Symposium on Computer Arithmetic*, 2015, indicates the relative cost for sin(x), cos(x) *roughly* as follows: IEEE-754 double precision (53-bit FP): 1x, 128-bit FP: 10x, 512-bit FP: 50x, 2048-bit FP: 500x. Number of instructions executed would be growing roughly by the same factors. Asymptotically,  basic transcendental functions (incl. sine) have complexity O(M(n)*log²(n)), where M(n) is the complexity of multiplication, where n*log(n) <= M(n) <= n**(1.58) [Karatsuba].

Comment: @rwallace Counting instructions for the DP sin() in a shipping math library, on the path for arguments |x| < 2**31, I count 35 instructions: 14 integer instructions, 13 FP64 FMAs, 6 64-bit loads, 1 FP64 comparison, 1 branch. Note that such statistics are likely to differ quite a bit based on ISA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... to assess the expected performance of calculating trigonometry functions as a function of the required precision.

Look as the first omitted term in the [Taylor series sine](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor+series+sin+x) for `x = π/4` as the order of error.

---

Details: `sin(x)` usually has these phases:

1. Handling **special cases**: NaN, infinities.
2. **Argument reduction** to the primary range to say [-π/4...+π/4].  *Real good* reduction is *hard* as π is irrational and so involves code that reaches 50% of `sin()` time.  Much time used to emulate the needed extended precision. (Research *K.C. Ng's "ARGUMENT REDUCTION FOR HUGE ARGUMENTS: Good to the Last Bit"*)
   Low quality reduction involves much less:`/`, truncate, `-`, `*`.
3. Calculation over a limited range.  This is what many only consider.   If done with a Taylor's series and needing 53 bits, then about 10-11 terms are needed: [Taylor series sine](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor+series+sin+x). Yet quality code often uses a pair of crafted polynomials, each of about 4-5 terms, to form the quotient p(x)/q(x).

- Of course dedicated hardware support in any of these steps greatly increases performance.
- Note: code for `sin()` is often paired with `cos()` code as extensive use of trig identities simplify the calculation.

I'd expect a software solution for `sin()` to cost on the order of 25x a common `*`.  This is a rough estimate.

To achieve a very low error rate in the [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place), code typically uses a tad more.  `sine_crap()` could get by with only a few terms.  So when assessing *time* performance, there is a trade-off with *correctness*.  How good a `sin()` do you want?

---

Answer (score 0):

> assess the expected performance of calculating trigonometry functions as a function of the required precision

Using the Taylors series as a predictor of the number of ops, worst case `x = π/4` (45°) and the error in the calculation on the order of the last term of the series:

[image: sin() Taylor's series]

[image: sin() Terms needed per Bits of precision]

For 32-bit `float`, order 6 `float` ops needed.
For 64-bit `double`, order 9 `float` ops needed.

So if *time* scales by the square of the FP width, `double`  predicted to take `9/6*2*2` or 6 times as long.